# DataIntegrityViolationException: Unable to store JSON Schema with spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a JSON schema as shown below which I am sending to my backend via websocket.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "user": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "user"
    ]
}
```

My bean class for this is defined as

```
class Schema{
    private String type;
    private String[] required;
    Private Map<String, Object> properties;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Now I want to store this in mongodb but when I try to do that I get below exception

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Write failed with error code 55 and error message 'The DBRef $ref field must be following by a $id field'; nested exception is com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: Write failed with error code 55 and error message 'The DBRef $ref field must be following by a $id field'
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:85) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2135) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:481) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.saveDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:1101) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1034) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:981) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I am guessing that $ref is not a valid key name to be used in mongodb but it is a valid key for JSON Schema based on Open API specifications and I want to tore it as is. 
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was sending the data through websocket which transmits it as a string, I am replacing `$ref` with some string (say `##ref##`) which is a valid key name for mongodb.

```
strData = strData.replace(new RegExp('"\\$ref":', 'g'), '"##ref##":');
self.stomp.send('/app/execute', {}, strData);
```

And when I receive it from backend, I again replace `##ref##` with `$ref`.

```
body = body.replace(new RegExp('"##ref##":', 'g'), '"$ref":');
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3229) mongodb JIRA, you can't save a key that contains `.` or starts with `$`. So, I believe the only solution here is to manually escape `$` before storing the object into `mondogb` and remove `\\` while retrieving it.

You can write this logic in the layer that deals with storage/retrieval of these objects.